# Save fragments state when using android BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Is there any out of the box solution to save fragments state when using [Android Bottom Navigation View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)? I have seen [this library](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) and [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011805/android-bottom-navigation-maintaining-activity-state) but I am looking for a **ready** solution which uses `Android Bottom Navigation` instead of a third party library. Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the above library (FragNav) is the only way I have found to save tab state like it is done in iOS. Android by default does not provide such functionality.

Comment: Yes, android currently does't support it and it fact, it just recently added support for `Bottom Navigation View`. I am looking for a library or class that has implemented this behaviour using android `Bottom Navigation View`. FragNav uses a 3rd party library to support `bottom navigation`.

Comment: I think that saving tab state in not possible using Bottom Navigation View and yes FragNav uses BottomBar library since it provides some helpful functions that is needed for the required task.